# How to hot deploy .jsp in JRebel when the rebel.load_embedded_plugins set to false?

Tags: java, jrebel, hotdeploy

I'm a noob in JRebel. In our project we have to set rebel.load_embedded_plugins to false because otherwise issues will occur. But at the same time we are not able to hot deploy the .jsp files in this project. In another word, after execute "ant deploy-jsp" we have to restart the whole server to see the effects. That is really time-wasting. Is there any way to hot deploy the .jsp files but keep rebel.load_embedded_plugins = false? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `rebel.load_embedded_plugins=false` to resolve a problem is like turning off electricity in whole building just because you wanted to turn off light in the bathroom. It disables whole lot of plugins that aren't actually causing any kind of issues for you. Send a trace-level `jrebel.log` as per [the manual](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/sending-log/) and server log to support@zeroturnaround.com with the description of the issue for them to find at least better temporary workaround.

It's also possible to disable plugins on individual basis. This is most easy to be done via plugins tab in the JRebel settings in IDE. Guess to which plugin is your error related to, disable it and check if the problem is still there.